# Graphing certain values from an array in python

Tags: python

I have a working Python code which produces a large array of values.

I can plot this extensive array using matplotlib.pyplot. I am trying to make my graph more legible, so to do this I would like to only plot certain values from the array.

For example if I run my code for $100$ iterations, rather than plotting the $100$ values I would like to plot just the first, tenth, twentieth, etc...

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Below is the end of my code  - $y$ prints an array of $11$ vectors ($10$ and an additional initial vector), I would like to only plot certain vectors from this array.

```
y = vectors(10,10)
print(x)

#plotting results
x = np.arange(0,10,1)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

**Edit**
Maybe this will help.

My formula calculates vectors for ranges of values of say $n$ over a range of times $t$. It then prints an array of vectors. Rather than graphing 100 vectors, I want to graph the vectors at t=0,10,20,30 up to t = 100

An example below is a printed array of vectors:

```
[[1.         0.5        0.2625     0.1434375  0.08110156 0.0472459 ]
 [0.         0.5        0.4875     0.3753125  0.26780469 0.1856252 ]
 [0.         0.         0.25       0.35625    0.35734375 0.31205078]
 [0.         0.         0.         0.125      0.23125    0.28320312]
 [0.         0.         0.         0.         0.0625     0.140625  ]]
```

When I use larger ranges of values these arrays are large, I need to get matplotlib to select certain vectors from this array.

Comment: Sure, just make a smaller array and plot that instead. `numpy` has a vast collection of [ways to index](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html) into existing arrays. Because `numpy` is clever, such indexing often constructs cheap view objects rather than making new arrays entirely.

Comment: Hey, can you provide more code ? I think `np.arange(...)` already supports different step sizes. Did you try `x = np.arange(0,10,3)` for example where `3` is a step size of three instead of one ?

Comment: Well under sampling may alter information conveyed by the figure, see aliasing. You also could consider aggregate when resampling in order to keep the meaningful information.

Answer (score 1):

make a new array to store only 10s values :

here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

time = np.arange(0, 100)
amplitude  = np.sin(time)

plot.plot(time, amplitude)
plot.show()
```

for full range 0 to 100 at step 1:

[image]

to get values at only 10s you can use the following code :

```
new_time = []

step = 10

for i in range(0, len(time), step):
    new_time.append(time[i])

plot.plot(new_time, np.sin(new_time))
plot.show()
```

[image]

`new_time` value is : `[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]`

### Edit :

another way of doing this :
if you have an array of shape (100, 5)

```
vector = np.random.randint(0, 100, (100, 5))  # shape (100, 5)
```

you can get the index position of 10s, 20s,... by :

```
step = 10
index_positions = list(range(0, len(vector), step))

new_vector = vector[index_positions]
```

output:

```
array([[72,  3, 14, 36,  3],
       [77, 79, 32, 75,  6],
       [62, 86,  5, 48, 30],
       [53, 80, 47, 60, 37],
       [99, 53, 64, 76, 88],
       [54, 73, 55, 27,  2],
       [23, 18, 79, 69,  5],
       [ 0, 43, 63, 34, 44],
       [69, 48, 16, 19, 20],
       [71, 95, 56, 30, 59]])
```

then you can plot these values by

```
plt.plot(new_vector)
```

Comment: Thanks! One issue however, my array is not just (1,2,3,4,5,6) etc... It prints an array of vectors with multiple values. I then need to select certain vectors to plot

Comment: What's the shape of the initial array?

Comment: I have an initial vector [1,0,0,0,0] (here t = 0 and n = [0,1,2,3,4]) So that initial condition gives V(0,0) =1 , V(1,0) = 0, V(2,0) = 0 etc... so as an example, if I ran my simulation for 2 values of t I would have an array with 2 (5-sized) vectors